# What is the physical significance of integration of xf(x)?

Tags: integration

I am an engineer and I mostly rely on my imagination and intuition to understand what a formula is actually trying to do. 
I understand that integration of f(x) over an interval means that we are trying to find something that will give us something having a squared unit, like an area
But when thinking about xf(x), it confuses me because I don't know it's significance yet. I mostly try to think of it as some area that has been integrated over am interval, but that's my limit. I cannot relate to any mnemonic. If you guys have some simple or even weird examples of real world where this integral plays a role, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: the reason why mathematics exists is precisely because many things are beyond the intuition. Mathematics and logic are methods created by the humanity to try to see beyond it limited intuition

Comment: P.S. : All this time, I have only used the formula of finding moment of inertia to help me imagine formulae like these. But when I see this applied to mean deviations in probability, it confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine a random variable with density $f(x)$. This means, intuitively, that the probability $X$ will fall in the interval $[x,x+dx)$ is $f(x)dx$. Hence the expected value of $X$ is summing up the values of $X$ multiplied by the "probability" that $X$ assumes $x$. In this sense $\int xf(x)dx$ is the expectation or weighted mean (centre of gravity) of $X$.

Comment: Maybe everyone uses the same moment of inertia or centre of gravity reference :P. As I have commented earlier, I have used that mnemonic only. Maybe I'm not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of a pole (stick, segment) of some length, and made of some material of density $d$, the total mass of the pole is "length times density".

If the material of the pole changes along its length (and also its density), the the total mass of the pole is the product of each length of material, times the length of that material, and sum up all pieces.

If it varies "continuously", then at each position "x" the density can be "f(x)", and the total mass needs to be computed by summing up infinite small pieces, i.e. making the integrate of x * f(x).

This is one application. Is it ok for you? :)

Comment: That's not correct. For the mass is $\int f(x) dx$, not $\int x f(x) dx$. It would apply for torque though, or moment of inertia.

Comment: It might be wrong as mentioned by @emacs drives me nuts. But it gives some intuition as to what we are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a function $f:D\to \Bbb R $ where $D$ is finite then the mean value of $f$ in $D$ is defined by

$$
\mu_D (f):=\frac{\sum_{x\in D}f(x)}{\sum_{x\in D}1}\tag1
$$

The number $\mu_D (f)$ represent the value that it will took $f$ in each point of $D$ if $f$ would be uniformly distributed (that is, if $f$ would be a constant function).

Because any integral can be approximated by a sequences of sums over finite sets (a Riemann sum or a simple function in the theory of Lebesgue) then the mean value of $f$ in an interval $D$ can be defined by

$$
\mu _D(f):=\frac{\int_D f(x) dx}{\int_D dx}\tag2
$$

But now if we set $f(x):=xg(x)$ for some $g$, what the integral of the map $x\mapsto xg(x)$ means? As the previous discussion, if we assumes that $\int_D dx=1$, then the integral
$$
\gamma (g):=\int_D xg(x)dx\tag3
$$
represent the mean value of $xg(x)$, that is, the value that will took $xg(x)$ if it would be uniformly distributed in $D$. Because $xg(x)$ means "position multiplied by value" then the constant $\gamma (g)$ gives the proportion that defines an idealized $g$ respect to the position to maintain a constant (probably signed) area (respect to the origin).

Despite the relation of $\mathrm{(3)} $ to the notion of expected value in probability theory it is far from easy to give an intuitive meaning to the integral of $xg(x)$. Indeed, in a measure theoretic context, the expected value is defined as a generalization of $\mathrm{(1)} $ and $\mathrm{(2)} $, that is

$$
\mu _{\Omega }(X)=\frac{\int_{\Omega }X\,\mathrm d P}{\int_{\Omega }\,\mathrm d P}=\int_{\Omega }X\,\mathrm d P=\mathbb{E}(X)\tag4
$$

for any measurable function $X:\Omega \to \Bbb R $ in a probability space $(\Omega ,P)$. Then the appearance of expressions like $\mathrm{(3)} $ is due to the push-forward of the probability measure $P$ induced by $X$ to $\Bbb R $, so it is not really intuitive.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. Maybe for now, I will think of it just weighted probability. Like when calculating the probability of deflection from actual target while firing a bullet. The more the value of our variate x having a probability higher than others, more the expected value will skew towards that point and would give us an idea about where the bullet is more likely to hit.